# How do I paint on the right side of the parent widget?

Tags: c++, qt, paint

I am creating a custom QScrollBar on top of the QScrollArea. I did `scroll_bar->setParent(acroll_area)` and now the ScrollBar::painEvent is painted on the QScrollArea, only problem is that it is painted on the left side. How do I get it to paint on the right side.

Comment: Did you call addScrollBarWidget on the scroll area?

Comment: @RA. no, i didnt want to do that because IIRC it would then place the scroll bar on the right of the content, not on top of it.

Comment: I see.  Then try calling setGeometry on your scroll bar to move it to the right -- this is supposed to place it relative to its parent (see QWidget::setGeometry).  If that doesn't work, try giving your scroll area a box  layout of some sort and place the scroll bar within the layout with an alignment to the right (see QWidget::setLayout and QBoxLayout::addWidget).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RA was correct, I called setGeometry and it worked fine :) (if you want to write your own answer, ill accept it)